# Where can I find updated MySQL roadmap?

Tags: mysql

I need to know when mysql 5.4 stable is planned to be released, but cannot find any updated roadmap. Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [goal](http://blogs.mysql.com/peterg/2009/05/20/mysql-54/) is that 5.4 will be GA in December 2009 (sigh). But have a look at [MySQL 2009-2010 roadmap](http://www.fishpool.org/post/2009/04/26/MySQL-2009-2010-roadmap).